# How to enable zoom to html docs for Android Application

Tags: android

I am developing an android application that requires to open html files stored in a server. These html files were initially in pdf format and I converted them to html using an online converter tool. 
I open these files through mobile device but it is not possible to zoom in-out (enable pinch zoom). Is there any way to enable pinch zoom?

Thanks

Comment: You can follow the following link
http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html It shows how to touch-zoom a view. You can just apply the same logic to your html file

Answer (score 1):

It should be easy. Just try:

```
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```